# Typescript- Apply ambient declaration to an unknown object

Tags: typescript

I have a external library "gapi" set to a property on the window object: window.gapi.  I'd like to keep it there but still use the @types/gapi declaration, something like:

```
import gapi from "@types/gapi"
const gapi = window.gapi as gapi
```

Can't seem to import it directly from node_modules either because it's ambient, ex:

```
import gapi from "./node_modules/@types/gapi/index.d.ts"
```

Very stuck on this if anyone understands how it works.  Thanks!

Comment: If you have the @types/gapi package already installed you shouldn't need to perform any additional imports. The package will augment the `window` interface for you and add the `gapi` property, and you can simply type `window.gapi.load(...)` etc.

Comment: Wow!! That just blew my mind @j_m4rtinez thanks so much for the info.  I'd been using (window as any).gapi the whole time.

Comment: @jm4rtinez How exactly does this work? I have npm installed the types, but not imported them. So my VS Code ts file does not know about them.

Comment: @Richard when you install the types package, they are placed into a `@types` folder within `node_modules`. This folder is given special treatment by the TypeScript compiler. All type declarations within this folder are made visible to your project without any additional configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make ensure you have added the types in your tsconfig file, not in your code.

First `npm install @types/gapi && npm install @types/gapi.auth2`

Then the `tsconfig.json` file must contain `{ "compilerOptions": { "types": ["gapi", "gapi.auth2"] }}`